# How to add new values into matlab's table based on a condition?

Tags: arrays, matlab

Considering having this table in matlab:

```
t = table([1; 0; 3; 1], [0; 1; 0; 4], 'VariableNames', {'A', 'B'});

A    B
_    _

1    0
0    1
3    0
1    4
```

I want to append a new column `C`with specific value that is based on a condition. Currently I use this loop:

```
for i=1:height(t)

    if t(i, 'A').Variables == 1
        t.C(i, 1) = 4;

    elseif t(i, 'A').Variables == 3
        t.C(i, 1) = 5;

    end

end
```

However, this is a time comsuming operation is case of a table size greater then 100k rows.

What would be the best solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
[t{t.A==1, 'C'}] = 4;
[t{t.A==3, 'C'}] = 5;
```

This uses the facts that

- Table contents can be indexed via `{}`, as in cell arrays;
- Table columns can be indexed by their name.

Or, as noted by [@SardarUsama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5698672/sardar-usama), you can use the simpler

```
t.C(t.A==1)=4;
t.C(t.A==3)=5;
```

This uses dot notation to index the column. The result is a numerical column vector, to which a scalar can be directly assigned.

Comment: or `t.C(t.A==1)=4;`   `t.C(t.A==3)=5;`

Comment: The second option does not seem to produce the same output as the first. `t.C` is a column vector in the first case, and a 4x4 matrix in the second case. (I'm on MATLAB R2017a, and using OP's definition of `t`). I get a warning: "Warning: The new variables being added to the table have fewer rows than the table. They have been extended with rows containing default values."

Comment: Ah, it has to be `t.C(t.A==1,1)=4; t.C(t.A==3,1)=5;` to explicitly index rows.

Comment: @CrisLuengo no such thing on R2018a

Comment: @SardarUsama: It was probably an "issue" that needed fixing. It certainly looks prettier your way. :)

Comment: @LuisMendo: This is why I added my version number. I didn’t think you guys would post stuff that doesn’t work. :)